# Solving an ODE with an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

Let $x$ be a twice differentiable equation. Suppose that the function $x$ satisfies the following integral equation:

$x(t)$ + $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} \frac{x(s)}{s + 1}\ ds= t+2$

Find the function $x$.

I tried finding the integral above by using integration by parts and differentiating $x(s)$ twice but it got really out of hand.

EDIT: Got it thanks to comments.

Comment: What if you take the derivative instead?

Comment: Derivative of which?

Comment: The entire equation - to see if you can get rid of the integral.

Comment: Holy f***, I'm a rising sophomore in University and I never knew that you could differentiate definite integrals. Thanks man, got the answer!

Comment: Can you add it as an answer and then accept it after the delay? Other people often raise such questions. You are welcome. Regards

Answer (score 3):

Differentiating $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} \frac{x(s)}{s + 1}\ ds$ with respect to $t$:

$ \displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}\ (\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} \frac{x(s)}{s + 1}\ ds) =$ $(\displaystyle\frac{x(t)}{t+1})' - (\displaystyle\frac{x(0)}{0+1})'$ = $\displaystyle\frac{x(t)}{t+1}$

Differentiating $x(t)$ + $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t} \frac{x(s)}{s + 1}\ ds= t+2$ with respect to $t$:

$x'(t) + \displaystyle\frac{x(t)}{t+1} = 1$

Multiplying by $t + 1$ throughout:

$(t +1)x'(t) + x(t) = t+1$

Solving the linear 1st-order ODE:

$(t+1)x(t) = \displaystyle\frac{t^2}{2} + t + C$

$x(t) = \displaystyle\frac{t^2}{2(t+1)} + \displaystyle\frac{t}{t+1} + \displaystyle\frac{C}{t+1}$